# java - k-means clustering

Tags: java, k-means, data-analysis

I have the following input integer vectors (example):

```
4 138 233 461 610 621 669 742 814 827
89 138 334 656 697 810
138
138 196 738
659 738
4 461
138 337 756 810
8 138 196 337 468 663 664 756 809 810
```

They all contain integer values [1-850] and are all stored in a csv file.

I want to divide them into multiple clusters based on similarities in the vectors, but I'm confused about how exactly to implement a k-means algorithm for my input data in java. Anyone willing to help out with tips or code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: we can help you if you actually have code. but we won't wite the code for you.

Comment: Do you have a specific question ? Helping out is too broad for SO.

Comment: Ehm, using a search engine is not possible?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for not posting code, but I'm just learning and I don't even know how to start with the code of the k-means algo, since I'm not even sure if that's right for my case. I don't want anyone to do the work for me, but any tips if I'm headed the right way will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Look at k-means in pseudo code and then write it in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo-code for k-means clustering

assuming you have a metric (let's call this M) which can compare input objects (in your case vectors) and output a measure of similarity.

and a function (let's call this A) which is capable of calculating the average of a collection of input objects

1. randomly select N items from your dataset. They are the new centers of the clusters (called centroids).
2. for each item X that isn't a centroid, calculate its distance to each centroid (using M), and mark it as belonging to that centroid C where the distance between X and C (using M) is smallest.
3. Each item is now assigned to a centroid.
4. Use the averaging function (A) to calculate the new centroids
5. Either use the output of A directly as the new centroids, or find actual items that are closest to the output of A (using M)
6. repeat steps 2 till 5 until convergence (or until your computational budget has been spent)

Also check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering